# Failed to get correlation key for `citrus_message_correlator_HttpClient`

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, citrus-framework

I have a CitrusEndpoints server configuration

```
@Bean
 public HttpServer myService() {
    return CitrusEndpoints.
             http().
             server().
             port(9999).
             timeout(10000).autoStart(true).build();
```

My client configuration

```
@Bean
public HttpClient httpClient() {
  return CitrusEndpoints.
           http().
           client().
           requestUrl("http://localhost:9999/myService/downloadSomething").
           contentType("multipart/form-data").
           build();
}
```

My unit test:

```
actions.$(http()
        .client(httpClient)
        .send()
        .get().path(id)
        .queryParam("version","1")
        .message().accept(ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA.getMimeType())
        .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token));
actions.$(http().server("http://localhost:9999/myService/downloadSomething/").receive().get( id).
        queryParam("version", "1"));
actions.$(http().server("http://localhost:9999/myService/downloadSomething/").respond().message().
        contentType(ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA.toString()));
actions.$(http().client(httpClient).receive().response(HttpStatus.OK)
        .message(new DefaultMessage(FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(new ClassPathResource("documents/somedoc.pdf").getFile())))
        .contentType(ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA.getMimeType()));
```

What I see

> com.consol.citrus.exceptions.TestCaseFailedException: Failed to get correlation key for `citrus_message_correlator_HttpClient`

P.S: If you notice any typos in the code, kindly ignore. I have attempted not to reveal any damning identification

Answer (score 1):

You try to send a request as a client and at the same time to receive another request as a server. As Http is a synchronous protocol by nature you need to use fork=true option on the 1st client send action.

This should solve the problem